# validates array elements inclusion using inclusion: { in: array }

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I use `acts-as-taggable-on` gem to populate a user interests on a `User` model like this

```
# User.rb
acts_as_taggable
acts_as_taggable_on :interests
```

As I populate the `interest_list` array, I need to check that the given values matches against a constant array to make sure these are accepted values, something like this

```
VALID_INTERESTS = ["music","biking","hike"]
validates :interest_list, :inclusion => { :in => VALID_INTERESTS, :message => "%{value} is not a valid interest" }
```

The code above returns the following error

```
@user = User.new
@user.interest_list = ["music","biking"]
@user.save
=> false …. @messages={:interest_list=>["music, biking is not a valid interest"]}
```

I can see the inclusion doesn't realize it should iterate over the array elements instead of s considering as a plain string but I'm not sure how to achieve this. Any idea?

Comment: This has been changed in Rails to work as you described it: https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/50649706d05e564eed4de9aa932dae2e5dd0f7ab

The answers below should no longer be necessary in most cases.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The standard inclusion validator will not work for this use case, since it checks that the attribute in question is a member of a given array. What you want is to check that *every* element of an array (the attribute) is a member of a given array.

To do this you could create a custom validator, something like this:

```
VALID_INTERESTS = ["music","biking","hike"]
validate :validate_interests

private

def validate_interests
  if (invalid_interests = (interest_list - VALID_INTERESTS))
    invalid_interests.each do |interest|
      errors.add(:interest_list, interest + " is not a valid interest")
    end
  end
end
```

I'm getting the elements of `interest_list` not in `VALID_INTERESTS` by taking the difference of these two arrays.

I haven't actually tried this code so can't guarantee it will work, but the solution I think will look something like this.

Comment: This is a quite common pattern, surprising I wasn't able to find (quickly) the gem to do this.

Answer (score 0):

It's a nice implementation, but I forget about one in the description of the model.

```
serialize : interest_list, Array
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), look around, and read through the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help). For single line answers, please use comments instead of creating a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your own `ArrayInclusionValidator`:

```
# app/validators/array_inclusion_validator.rb
class ArrayInclusionValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    # your code here

    record.errors.add(attribute, "#{attribute_name} is not included in the list")
  end
end
```

In the model it looks like this:

```
# app/models/model.rb
class YourModel < ApplicationRecord
  ALLOWED_TYPES = %w[one two three]
  validates :type_of_anything, array_inclusion: { in: ALLOWED_TYPES }
end
```

Examples can be found here:

- https://github.com/sciencehistory/kithe/blob/master/app/validators/array_inclusion_validator.rb
- https://gist.github.com/bbugh/fadf8c65b7f4d3eaa55e64acfc563ab2