# Multiple select in collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I would know how i can allow multiple selection on my field

I have a simple_form field like this

```
<%= f.input :activity, required: true, autofocus: true, label: "Votre Activité", collection: ["Vente", "Location", "Gestion", "Syndic"] %>
```

In my controller

```
devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:password, :password_confirmation, :photo, :address, :cover, :activity)
```

My model

```
validates :activity, inclusion: { in: %w(Vente Location Syndic Gestion),
        message: "%{value} n'est pas un mandat valide"}
```

I tried this [way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22159614/ruby-on-rails-4-simple-form-multiple-select-input) but it doesnt work, i think the problem from the activity variable type

Comment: is your `:activity` attribute a String? or is it a Postgres Text Array (if you're using Postgres)? i.e. what does it show in your schema.rb; is it `t.string :activity`, or `t.text :activity, array: true`?

Comment: activity is a string @Jay-ArPolidario

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**app/models/your_model.rb**:

```
class YourModel < ApplicationRecord
  serialize :activity, Array # add this

  # you can't use `inclusion:` validation because it is only for validating a single value
  # so you'll do something like this, or if you want it to clean it a bit by defining a method instead, see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13579357/validates-array-elements-inclusion-using-inclusion-in-array
  validate do
    unless %w(Vente Location Syndic Gestion).include? activity
      errors.add(:activity, "#{activity} n'est pas un mandat valide"
    end
  end
end
```

**app/views/.../some_view.html.erb**:

```
<%= f.input :activity,
      required: true,
      autofocus: true,
      label: "Votre Activité",
      collection: ["Vente", "Location", "Gestion", "Syndic"],
      input_html: { multiple: true },
      include_hidden: false
%>
```

- I added `input_html: { multiple: true }` above so that the `params` will be an array of values instead of just a single value
- I added that `include_hidden: false` above because without it you'll get something like

  ```
  ["", "Location", "Syndic"]
  ```

  which adds an empty string instead of just..

  ```
  ["Location", "Syndic"]
  ```

  - more info [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/5402)

**app/controllers/some_controller.rb**:

```
devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(
  :account_update,
  keys: [
    :password,
    :password_confirmation,
    :photo,
    :address,
    :cover,
    activity: [] # change this from :activity
  )
```

*Tested working*